# Setting socket.io client 'resource' for nginx reverse proxying path (no websockets)

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

I have a socket.io server only using the 'xhr-polling' transport running at port 5000 on a system with nginx configured to pass requests that start with '/api' to that port.

In my client, on connect, I specify the socket.io resource as 'api/socket.io' which appears to correctly forward the initial connection request to the server and trigger a connection event. However, responses sent from the server using `socket.emit` do not reach the client.

If I connect the client directly to port 5000, leave off the 'resource' option, and bypass nginx forwarding, everything seems to work ok.

Server:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(5000, {transports: ['xhr-polling']});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
   console.log('Connection spotted!');
   socket.emit('connected', 'hi');
});
```

Client (not working):

```
var socket = io.connect(window.location.hostname, {resource:'api/socket.io'});
socket.on('connected', function(data) {
    alert('Connected!!!');
});
```

Client (working):

```
var socket = io.connect(window.location.hostname, {port: 5000});
socket.on('connected', function(data) {
    alert('Connected!!!');
});
```

nginx:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
}
```

In both cases I see the "Connection spotted!" log message on the server, but client gets data and alerts when connected directly to the port.

Comment: Have you been able to solve the issue? I am stuck at the similar one. This is my question if you could please help:
http://serverfault.com/questions/699451/nginx-reverse-proxy-for-apache-and-socket-io-on-a-ssl-enabled-site